# How to configure DNS and mail on cPanel

Tags: php, email, dns, cpanel, record

I have IP address and domain bedbids.com Now I need to connect IP with domain and that works good but also I need to configure mail client on other server...

My DNS looks like this:

[image]

Also my MX entries looks like this:

[image]

What will be proper configuration for my domain... so I send only bedbids.com and www.bedbids.com on new server IP address but I want mail to stay at same address as now...

How to do that... So redirection works good now but I dont receive mails...

Comment: Not use MX for edit DNS records if you are root or reseller on Cpanel. Directly use Edit DNS. On Image do **Edit DNS** not show information about MX. With a simple test (on comment below) your DNS has not a MX entry. Thre're a problem between your images and reality. Double check Edit DNS for search correct entry for MX.

Comment: `dig @ns1.performous.com bedbids.com` not show any entry. That is signal for error on DNS entry. Has not a MX entry.

Comment: so how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Edit your DNS Entry for **bedbids.com** Adn a line with bedbids.com 14400 IN MX 0 bedbids.com.

Answer (score 0):

WHM DNS Zone screen-capture doesn't show MX record as following:

[image]

If it is not present, please add it from the same DNS zone edit page at the bottom.

Currently, DNS checker is unable to find any MX record for the domain. http://www.intodns.com/bedbids.com

Generally, any DNS record update takes 24-48 hours to get propagated over the globe.

Comment: Not need 24-48 for test a correct DNS configuration, neither need a external tools. Simple, use dig, nslookup, or other tools for ask directlry to delegate NAMSERVER. `dig @NS1.PERFORMOUS.COM MX bedbids.com` not show any MX. `dig +short @NS1.PERFORMOUS.COM  bedbids.com`show `13.94.234.213`

Comment: If MX Record entry like my given screen capture is not showing on "Edit DNS zone" page of Your WHM.

Scroll down the page & add new record with details:

domain name = bedbids.com ,
TTL = 14400 ,
Record Type=MX ,
Priority = 0 ,
MX Record= bedbids.com 

Once you will add it, the record entry will took like my given screen-capture in answer.